# TeamCity Backup on schedule and copy to Azure, REST script improvements

Tags: azure, powershell, teamcity

I was working on a script to run TeamCity backups on a scheduled basis, as by default it doesn't have such an option, and then copy it to Azure storage account.

The script is working but I want to do some improvement.

1. I want Powershell to check backup file availability for download (Test-Path or etc.) For now, it just takes sleep for 360 seconds.
2. I want to configure the retention policy on the Azure storage account.

> ```
> #API key for TeamCity as TC parameter
> $key = "%key%"
>
> $date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
>
> $file = "TeamCity-Backup-$date.zip"
>
> #URI for initialize backup
> $uri = "https://teamcity.test.com/app/rest/server/backup?addTimestamp=false&includeConfigs=true&includeDatabase=true&includeBuildLogs=false&fileName=$file"
>
>
> #URI for downloading backup
> $uri1 = "https://teamcity.test.com/get/file/backup/$file"
>
>  $header = @{  "Authorization"="Bearer $key"  }
>
> #Initialize
> Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Header $header   
>
> #Wait for backup
> sleep -Seconds 360
>
> #
> #Need function or method for checking file availibility
> #
>
> #Download
> Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri1 -Header $header -OutFile "$file"
>
> #Key to BLOB
> $key_storage = "%key_storage%"
>
> #Copy to Azure
> azcopy.exe copy $file "https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/teamcity-backups$key_storage"
>
> #
> #Funtion for retention Azure Blob
> #
> ```

Comment: From where you will be running this script?

Comment: Have you checked out the [Az.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-3.8.0) module?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS from TeamCity